# Search Form Htaccess rewrite

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have a htaccess rules that are not working well, it looks like its not assuming almost all of them, if i put only one rule it works fine, the problem is when i insert all of them, here is my code above.

```
# Search Form Url Result
#search by category
RewriteRule ^jobs/([^/\.]+)$ jobs.php?Category=$1

#search by location
RewriteRule ^jobs/([^/\.]+)$ jobs.php?Location=$1

#search by category and location
RewriteRule ^jobs/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ jobs.php?Category=$1&Location=$2
```

Basically each rule is for each situation, for example if the user search only for category or location, or even search for category and location.

Comment: Rule1 and Rule2 are using same patter so only 1st will work.

Comment: @anubhava sorry, i forgot to change it, but the issue still exist even when i change there patter to for example Location=$2. And yes, only the 1st is working.

Comment: @anubhava so how can i resolve this issue?

Comment: How do you determine whether the string after `jobs/` is a category or a location? Is `jobs/php` a location? Is `jobs/chicago` a category?

Comment: @Cryszon basically by is name, i guess based in the rule "jobs.php?Location=" or "jobs.php?Category=" determines the type of information that it is, sorry if im not quite correct since regex is not quite my strong side.

Comment: @Cryszon but i guess what is the problem, i have to give a unique label "jobs/.." to make it work, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `Rule1` and `Rule2` are using same pattern i.e. `^jobs/([^/\.]+)$` so only 1st will work.

You have to add an appropriate identifier after `/jobs/` to distinguish between category and location URIs.

You may consider:

```
# Search Form Url Result

#search by category
RewriteRule ^jobs/c/([^/.]+)/?$ jobs.php?Category=$1 [L,QSA]

#search by location
RewriteRule ^jobs/l/([^/.]+)/?$ jobs.php?Location=$1 [L,QSA]

#search by category and location
RewriteRule ^jobs/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ jobs.php?Category=$1&Location=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, totally understood the problem.